# Проверка на число в функции

Tags: javascript

Нужно сделать так чтобы когда вводят не число, в функцию `prime`, появилось сообщение, что нужно ввести только число.

```js
prime(25);

function prime(num) {
  var i;
  var num;

  for (i = 2; i < num; i++) {
    if (num % i === 0) {
      document.write("this number " + num + " is not a prime number");

      return false;
    }

    document.write("this number " + num + " is a prime number");

    return true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
prime('qwerty');

function prime(num) {

  // проверяем тип входящего параметра
  if (typeof num !== 'number')
    throw new Error('PLEASE ENTER NUMBER')
  // или
  // document.write("PLEASE ENTER NUMBER");
  // return

  for (let i = 2; i < num; i++) {
    if (num % i === 0) {
      document.write("this number " + num + " is not a prime number");
      return false;
    }

    document.write("this number " + num + " is a prime number");
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: @lolrekto так и задумано. Видите строчку `throw new Error('PLEASE ENTER NUMBER')`? Она выдает ошибку.

Comment: "this number 9 is a prime number" :)

Comment: @Yaant вопрос етого не касался )